# Aside element float on left margin

Tags: css, css-float

I am looking to create a style rule that sets the width of the aside element to 768 pixels and floats it on the left margin.

This is my code so far

```
aside {
  width: 768px;
  float: left;
}
```

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong here; but if it doesn't [have a height or text in it, then you're not going to see anything!](https://jsfiddle.net/h98ksygz/).

Comment: you may find https://internetingishard.com/html-and-css/floats/ to be helpful!